# "Attempt to read property \"id\" on string" laravel api

Tags: php, laravel, api, postman

ProductController.php

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $limit = $request->has('limit') ? $request->get('limit') : 10;
        $offset = $request->has('offset') ? $request->get('offset') : 0;

        $products = Product::offset($offset)->limit($limit)->get();
        return new ProductResource($products);
    }
    //Search Products
    public function search($name, Request $request)
    {
        $limit = $request->has('limit') ? $request->get('limit') : 10;
        $offset = $request->has('offset') ? $request->get('offset') : 0;

        $products = Product::where('name', 'like', '%' . $name . '%')
            ->offset($offset)->limit($limit)->get();
        return new ProductResource($products);
    }

}
```

ProductResource.php

```
class ProductResource extends JsonResource
{
 
    public function toArray($request)
    {

        foreach ($request->all() as $product) {
            $response = [
                'id' => "p" . $product->id,
                'name' => $product->name,
                'slug' => $product->slug,
                'regular_price' => $product->regular_price,
                'sale_price' => $product->sale_price,
                'SKU' => $product->SKU,
                'stock_status' => $product->stock_status,
                'quantity' => "p" . "$product->quantity",
                'image' => $product->url,
                'images' => $product->url,
                'category_id' => $product->category_id,

            ];
            $responses[] = $response;

        }
        return response($responses, 201);

    }
}
```

This is my get route from api (http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products?limit=5&offset=0)
when send,
"message": "Attempt to read property "id" on string",
"file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DNI_E_commerce/app/Http/Resources/ProductResource.php",
"line": 20,

Comment: `$product->id` - `$product` is a string. You're going through `$request->all()`, so that doesn't contain what you think it contains.

Comment: how can I retrieve data ?

Comment: you seem to want to use a resource collection to pass the collection to, not a single `JsonResource` instance ... the `JsonResource` is for a single resource, not a collection of resources .... and you are not using the `toArray` method correctly (you are supposed to return an array, hence why it is named `toArray`) also `$request` is actually a `Request` object, it is not what you pass to the constructor of the `JsonResource` (you are not directly calling `toArray`) ... https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#concept-overview read this and the next subsection (Resource Collections)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Search function, you can just return $products that you get from your ->get() query.
$products is a laravel collection of all the products matching the search query in the DB. A collection is basically a fancy object. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections

If you do that, you should be able to use the toArray() function as is, but you can also just loop through the collection without making it into an array first.

Comment: I return in controller and then OK